# Pass through ODIN MODE

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, factory-reset, hard-reset

I have a Samsung J3 6 (2016), I'm trying to hard reset (PIN loss).

I found out that I should hold <kbd>Volume Up</kbd>+<kbd>Power</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> for several seconds. Then I am warned that downloading a costum OS might be dangerous, I continue by press <kbd>Volume Up</kbd>.

I finally get stuck with a big droid and "*Downloading...* Do not turn off target !!" and also

```
ODIN MODE
SECURE DOWNLOAD: ENABLE
MOM DOWNLOAD BLOCK: 0
PRODUCT NAME: SM-J320FN
CURREN BIN: Samsung Official
SYSTEM STATUS: Official
FAP LOCK: ON
USB Init Start!
USB core reset done!
```

It's the same screen since 6 hours, is there a way to make the download complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happend to me on J3  2017, I left it for more than 48 hours but nothing. Then phone batery ran out, so phone reseted and firmware was deleted. I needed to download new firmware with Odin to phone  from https://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/. It took me 8 hours too download it, becaose that site  has Premium with normal download speed, but you need to pay for it.

ODIN DOWNLOAD
Put file in Odin and start downloading. 
That process will fail hidden(it should fail) and you need to make a last step manulay. Link for official Sammobile tutorial :https://www.sammobile.com/forum/threads/35929-SOLVED-firmware-flashing-FAIL-after-hidden-img

I do not know if is this going to help you, but you can reset phone with this method to a state before you start this. And if you do everything good you wont loose your data.

And for PIN reset you can just make hard reset :Volume Up + Home + Power button for a couple of seconds and navigate with Volume button to hard reset. It will wipe all of your data to factory settings(if you have Samsung Acc. backup everything will be safe), including PIN code, but you need to input your gmail pasword (if you have gmail on phone) to unlock it,or phone will be locked.

Comment: http://fw.updato.com